# Adding a class to before and after links in a for statement using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a list of links in a UL. Can someone give me an example of how to detect what the index is of the link that was clicked, then add one class to all the links in LIs before the selected link and a different class to all the links in LIs after the selected link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ul = document.getElementById('your-ul'),
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

var iterateLi = function(fn) {
    for (var i = 0, length = li.length; i < length; i++) {
        fn.call(li[i], i);
    }
};

iterateLi(function(index) {
    var thisIndex = index,
        thisLi = this;

    this.onclick = function(index) {
        iterateLi(function(index) {
            var classes = ['before', 'selected', 'after'],
                addClass;
            if (index < thisIndex) {
                addClass = classes[0];
            } else if (index == thisIndex) {
                addClass = classes[1];
            } else {
                addClass = classes[2];
            }

            for (var i = 0, length = classes.length; i < length; i++) {
            }

            var className = this.className;

            if (className) {
                var regex = new RegExp('(?:' + classes.join('|') + ')', 'g');
                className = className.replace(regex, '');
                console.log(regex, className)
            }

            this.className = className + ' ' + addClass;
        });
    };
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/65C2F/).

Comment: Thanks! Can you make it so it will add a "selected" class to the clicked LI instead of "after"?

Comment: Thanks again! For some reason, it's not responding to my clicks after I click one time?

Comment: @Zoolander It only works the first time, you'd need to remove the other classes for each next click.